# How to validate dropdown list and save them in database, and code doesnt shows errors

Tags: java, php, html, database

Okey. I create form, some php code to save that in database. That works fine. 
I have problem with this:
- Code doesnt shows errors when user let inputs empty.
- How to validate select form so user has to pick one, and how to save that pick in base with others, I think I have problem with column type in database.

For example, If I have select form with name "bikes" and I have list of 10 bikes, how to validate them so user has to pick one bikes from list and how to store his pick in database, and where is error because code not shows errors when user let inputs empty. As I said, when user put information in inputs area program save that fine in base, but no errors when use let inputs empty.

Sorry for my bad english.

Here is code, i hope you will understand it, cuz variables are not on English.

```
  <?php
  // Initialize the session
  session_start();

  // Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login 
 page
  if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
  header("location: login.php");
  exit; 
  }
  ?>



 <?php
 if(!empty($_POST["send"])) {
$imeKor = $_POST["imeKor"];
$prezimeKor = $_POST["prezimeKor"];
$brojTelefonaKor = $_POST["brojTelefonaKor"];
$godineKor = $_POST["godineKor"];
$emailKor = $_POST["emailKor"];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "it210Projekat") or 
   die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO bazarezervisanihvozila (imeKor, 
    prezimeKor,brojTelefonaKor,godineKor, emailKor) VALUES ('" . $imeKor.  
    "', '" . $prezimeKor. "','" . $brojTelefonaKor. "','" . $godineKor. 
    "', '" . $emailKor."')");
$insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
//if(!empty($insert_id)) {
   $uspesnaPoruka1 = "Uspesno ste rezervisali vozilo!.";
   $type = "Uspesno";
//}
   }
   require_once "pocetna.php";
   ?>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateReservation() {
        var valid = true;

        $(".info").html("");
        $(".input-field").css('border', '#e0dfdf 1px solid');
        var imeKor = $("#imeKor").val();
        var prezimeKor = $("#prezimeKor").val();
        var brojTelefonaKor = $("#brojTelefonaKor").val();
        var godineKor = $("#godineKor").val();
        var emailKor = $("#emailKor").val();


        if (imeKor == "") {
            $("#imeKor-info").html("Ovo polje ne moze biti prazno.");
            $("#imeKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }

        if (prezimeKor == "") {
            $("#prezimeKor-info").html("Ovo polje ne moze biti prazno.");
            $("#prezimeKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }

        if (brojTelefonaKor == "") {
            $("#brojTelefonaKor-info").html("Ovo polje ne moze biti prazno.");
            $("#brojTelefonaKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!brojTelefonaKor.match(/^\d*$/.test(value))
        {
            $("#brojTelefonaKor-info").html("Broj telefona nije validan.");
            $("#brojTelefonaKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }

        if (godineKor == "") {
            $("#godineKor-info").html("Ovo polje ne moze biti prazno.");
            $("#godineKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!godineKor.match(/^\d*$/.test(value))
        {
            $("#brojTelefonaKor-info").html("Godine nisu validne.");
            $("#brojTelefonaKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (emailKor == "") {
            $("#emailKor-info").html("Ovo polje ne moze biti prazno.");
            $("#emailKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!emailKor.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/))
        {
            $("#emailKor-info").html("Email adresa nije validna.");
            $("#emailKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

```
<body>
    <div class="form-container">
    <form name="frmContact1" id="" frmContact1"" method="post"
     action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        onsubmit="return validateReservation()">

        <div class="input-row">
            <label style="padding-top: 20px;">Ime</label> <span
                id="imeKor-info" class="info"></span><br /> <input
                type="text" class="input-field" name="imeKor"
                id="imeKor" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label>Prezime</label> <span id="prezimeKor-info"
                class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                class="input-field" name="prezimeKor" id="prezimeKor" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label>Broj telefona</label> <span id="brojTelefonaKor-info"
                class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                class="input-field" name="brojTelefonaKor" id="brojTelefonaKor" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label>Godine</label> <span id="godineKor-info"
                class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                class="input-field" name="godineKor" id="godineKor" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label>Email</label> <span id="emailKor-info"
                class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                class="input-field" name="emailKor" id="emailKor" />
        </div>
        <select name="izborMotoraKor">
        <option value="0">Izaberite motor</option>
        <option value="1">MOTOWELL CROGEN CITY</option>
        <option value="2">MOTOWELL CROGEN RS2</option>
        <option value="3">ASR Aprilia</option>
        <option value="4">Beneli Velvet</option>
        <option value="5">MOTOWELL CROGEN RS3</option>
        <option value="6">Yamaxa XMAS</option>
        <option value="7">Sprint Grizzy 125</option>
        <option value="8">Sprint Explorer</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn-submit"
                value="Posalji" />

            <div id="statusMessage"> 
                    <?php
                    if (! empty($poruka)) {
                        ?>
                        <p class='<?php echo $type; ?>Poruka'><?php echo $uspesnaPoruka1; ?></p>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

`

```
$izborMotoraKor = $_POST["izborMotoraKor"]; mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT 
    INTO 
    bazarezervisanihvozila (imeKor, prezimeKor,brojTelefonaKor,godineKor, 
    emailKor, 
   izborMotoraKor) VALUES ('" . $imeKor. "', '" . $prezimeKor. "','" . 
   $brojTelefonaKor. "','" . $godineKor. "', '" . $emailKor."', '" . 
   $izborMotoraKor"')");

  if (izborMotoraKor == "") {
            $("#izborMotoraKor-info").html("Ovo polje ne moze biti 
 prazno.");
            $("#izborMotoraKor").css('border', '#e66262 1px solid');
            valid = false;
        }
```

`

Comment: This should be done in html or js. Can you post html code with form ?

Comment: I updated answer with html form. @bakero98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specifie input to be **required** . This is html sintax for every possible input. Form will not execute if any of requied inputs, selects, radioboxes is not selected.

> Select required

```
<select required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   ...
</select>
```

> Input required

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

> Radio buttons. To group radio buttons use same name attribute. This allows only one to be selected at the time and applies required to the whole group

```
    Select Gender:

  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
```

> Code snippet for required

```html
<form>

<select required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Chose Car')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  >
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
<br>

<input type="text" name="usrname" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter Username')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  >
<br>
    Select Gender:

  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Chose Gender')"
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  >Male</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
<br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

> You SHOULD always us preparedStatement for injection security. This is php code that is storing your input in database.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "it210Projekat");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// set parameters
if(!empty($_POST["send"])) {
$imeKor = $_POST["imeKor"];
$prezimeKor = $_POST["prezimeKor"];
$brojTelefonaKor = $_POST["brojTelefonaKor"];
$godineKor = $_POST["godineKor"];
$emailKor = $_POST["emailKor"];
$izborMotoraKor = $_POST["izborMotoraKor"];
}

// prepare, bind and execute
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bazarezervisanihvozila (imeKor, prezimeKor,brojTelefonaKor,godineKor, emailKor, izborMotoraKor) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssiiss", $imeKor, $prezimeKor, $brojTelefonaKor, $godineKor, $emailKor, $izborMotoraKor);
$stmt->execute();



$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

> If you use integer and you first number is 0 (example 067223212) it will not be saved in database ( Database will lsave 67223221 ).

Comment: Thank you for this, but can you help me how I can save user choice from select list in database?

EDIT: Also, because I have two inputs where user need to input just numbers, so how I can make that input just for numbers... if user input strings message should be "just numbers"...

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic `$selected_val = $_POST['izborMotoraKor'];` this will get you value of options. if user chose `MOTOWELL CROGEN CITY` this will return `1` and so on

Comment: I tried like that already but wont save user pick in database. What type of column need to be? varchar?

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic varchar can store all characters and that is not problem. Can you update your php code with code of getting from  `<select name="izborMotoraKor">` ?

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic give me table collumn types please

Comment: korIme, korPrezime, korEmail and izborMotoraKor is varchar, godineKor i brojTelefonaKor is integer

Comment: Yeah, now works, but on database column show me number of user pick no motor name, so if user pick motor and that motor is 3rd on list in base stay 3 no name of motor, and also, I cant see message that process is succesfull even I made it

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic in select change `<option value="1">MOTOWELL CROGEN CITY</option>` to `<option value="MOTOWELL CROGEN CITY">MOTOWELL CROGEN CITY</option>` and like that for every option. Value is what you get in php variable with `$_POST` and that is what is going to be stored in database

Comment: Yeah, that should fix my problem. Thank you, and just one more, as you can see at first I made for every input different requires so user can input just numbers for korGodine, but when he inputs string program also works, even I made a code for that, and when I submit all inputs empty page just refreshed herself, even I also made a code for that to print errors on each input its empty? can you help me with that

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic `<input type="number">` . It should not  refresh as you can see in code snippet. Update your question with new code. Kako je na Metropolitanu

Comment: Dobro je brate ti si BG? Zezaju me padezi na eng. Problem mi je ovo sto zelim da mi izbaci pored inputa gresku ako korisnik nije uneo validan podatak, radi mi perfetkno na drugoj strani ali ovde kad posaljem prazne podatke samo mi refresuje stranicu

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic Mora na engleski ovdje. I updated my code snippet for you to try now with custom error messages

Comment: Okay, but as you can see I have godineKor so I want to make that input just for numbers, so how to make code so program recognize when user input strings and disable submit button until user change it to numbers

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic Change `<input type="text">` to `<input type="number">` if you are working in HTML5

Comment: Okey, and for valid email? What if user input in email just asdf@.com

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic `<input type="email">`

Comment: Ima me, Стефан Јанковић, profilna grb Mancester Sitija

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value in your PHP script, like your other form inputs.

```
$izborMotoraKor = $_POST["izborMotoraKor"];
```

Comment: I already tried that but doesnt work, others value were saved in base but that one no

Comment: Strange... I've just tried it with your Select and Options, and it works fine. Are you expecting a Number ("0") or String ("Izaberite motor") to be returned?

Comment: I made it, and now works but not how I want, because in my base program save on which position was user pick, so if he pick item from 3rd position in database is 3 no name of that item

Comment: @MilivojeCirkovic You can change the values to the actual names in your options then. `value="Izaberite motor"`